# Why isn't this return statement doing anything?

Tags: java, return, control-flow

I have this code, which checks whether the brackets in a string like "{{}[]}" are in a valid order:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BraceChecker {
  private static HashMap<String,String> dict=new HashMap<>(){{
    put(")","(");
    put("]","[");
    put("}","{");
  }};
  public boolean isValid(String braces) {
    Stack<String> stack=new Stack<>();
    for(String s:braces.split("")){
      if(dict.get(s)==null){
        stack.push(s);
        System.out.println("test");
      }
      else
        try{
          if(!stack.pop().equals(dict.get(s))){
            System.out.println("what");
            return false;
          }
        }catch(EmptyStackException e){return false;}
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

For each character in the string, if it's an opening bracket it adds it to the stack, and if it's a closing bracket it removes an item. If the removed item doesnt match the equivalent bracket to the one in the input string, it SHOULD return false.

But when the program is run on the string "[(])", which chould return false, it returns true. The System.out.printlns produce this:

```
test
test
what
test
what
test
what
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

But why doesn't the program return false when it gets to the first 'what'? And how can I make it return false?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Solution {

  // Hash table that takes care of the mappings.
  private HashMap<Character, Character> mappings;

  // Initialize hash map with mappings. This simply makes the code easier to read.
  public Solution() {
    this.mappings = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    this.mappings.put(')', '(');
    this.mappings.put('}', '{');
    this.mappings.put(']', '[');
  }

  public boolean isValid(String s) {

    // Initialize a stack to be used in the algorithm.
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);

      // If the current character is a closing bracket.
      if (this.mappings.containsKey(c)) {

        // Get the top element of the stack. If the stack is empty, set a dummy value of '#'
        char topElement = stack.empty() ? '#' : stack.pop();

        // If the mapping for this bracket doesn't match the stack's top element, return false.
        if (topElement != this.mappings.get(c)) {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        // If it was an opening bracket, push to the stack.
        stack.push(c);
      }
    }

    // If the stack still contains elements, then it is an invalid expression.
    return stack.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

This code definitely works. I couldn't debug your code but this is a runnable solution of the same.